Why does Pandas rolling method return a series with a different dtype to the original?
Just curious why the Pandas Series rolling window method doesn't preserve the data-type of the original series:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.ones(6), dtype='float32')
x.dtype, x.rolling(window=3).mean().dtype

Output:
(dtype('float32'), dtype('float64'))


x.rolling(window=3) gives you a pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling object. help(pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean) includes the note:
 Returns
-------
Series or DataFrame
    Return type is the same as the original object with ``np.float64`` dtype.

that's the little why. The big why it would do such a thing, I don't know. Perhaps it's a way to keep from losing precision since you can always choose to convert to float32 again.

I'm not sure what "return type is the same as the original object with np.float64 dtype" means.  Does it mean "return type is np.float64" (i.e. not same as original), or "return type is the same as the original object" (i.e. not necessarily np.float64)?

I think 'type' refers to Series, DataFrame, etc... but dtype is float64. So, a DataFrame of integers would be a DataFrame of float64.
